# Accordion control bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I am using the following code to build an accordion in my symfony project.

https://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ#

The accordion works correctly as long as we do not click on the top buttons. Pressing to show everything and then open or close some manually, when you click on show everything does not show all correctly again, some are displayed and others are hidden.

I have also tried adding the following code in each action of the buttons

```
 $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('collapsed');

 $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('collapsed');
```

To test the problem, if you press the combination: 2, 3 and then Sow all, you will see the problems (at this point, you can press repeatedly on Show all).

Can you tell me why this malfunction is due?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that I had to activate the content as a collapsible element.

```
$('#CollapsibleExample').collapse ({ toggle: false })
```